# How to specify bootstrap columns and rows for posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my posts on my wordpress installation appear as a "col-md-6" Full sized preview then a "col-md-6" & "row" to show to horizontally split different posts.

Here is my code to get them appear as seperate blocks - but I want this type of setup:
TOP OF PAGE
| Post1  |  Post2  | *break*
| Post1  |  Post 3 |

Here is my code so far:

```
     <?php 

  $x = 1;

  $args = array('cat'=> 107, 'order'=>'ASC' );
    query_posts( $args);

    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 center">
       <div class="lightgrey_bg">
           <div class="explore_icon 
     <?php if ($x == 1) {echo 'red_bg';} 
     elseif ($x == 2) {echo 'green_bg';} 
     elseif ($x == 3) {echo 'orange_bg';} ?>">

     <?php the_title(); ?>
           </div>
         <div class="tile_text"><?php echo the_field('solutions_excerpt', $post_id );?></div>

       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <br />
     </a> <!-- closes the first div box -->

     <?php 
   if ($x == 3) {$x = 1;} else {$x ++;};
  endwhile;  ?>

   </div>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what the intended appearance is and what the current problem is? Do you want 2 columns? 3 columns?